# Tarballs w/ MapReduce or Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

A colleague of mine was telling me that he didn't see any issues with using tarballs to hold the data sent to a MapReduce job. My understanding of how Hadoop and MR/Spark work together is that the preferred hadoop storage formats are designed so that the data files can be split along the Hadoop block size and fanned out to MR mappers or Spark workers (to be partitioned). Tar strikes me as a really terrible format to do this because AFAIK Tar is absolutely not in any way designed to accommodate the way Hadoop and its various job engines work. Am I missing something here?